# есть ли разница между int* ptr и int *ptr?

Tags: c++

если есть разница,то в чем?Обьясните пожалуйста,вроде и статьи читал,но не могу понять в чем разница.

Comment: ¿Почему вы решили, что есть разница? ¿А что на счет `int * ptr`? Или `int   *   ptr`

Comment: да,я видел такое написание,но почему то не подумал об этом.Спасибо за ответ